# How to use R shiny to filter a specific column from a csv file and extract the data in csv and pdf format

Tags: r, shiny

As I am new to R shiny, please go easy on me:
I have found this code useful: https://community.rstudio.com/t/download-dataset-filtered-in-shiny-input/75770. This code takes Iris data and filters based on the column 'Species'

In order to get the filtering results after uploading my own data via `fileInput()` I made some adjustments to the code above. I am trying to filter data using the column 'Type', but I am receiving the below-mentioned error.

**Error:**

```
object 'file1' not found
```

**csv data:**

```
ID  Type    Range
21  A1     100
22  C1     200
23  E1     300
```

**code**:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  #setBackgroundColor(color = c("#66e0ff", "#00a3cc", "#003d4d")),
  h1("Data"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(fileInput("file1", label = "Choose species"),
                 downloadButton("download1","Download entire Table  as csv")),
    mainPanel(h4("Table 1: Iris"),
              dataTableOutput("csv_dto")
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$csv_dto <- renderTable({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
  
  thedata <- reactive({
    file$datapath %>% 
      filter(Type == input$Type)
  })
  
  output$type_dto <- renderDataTable({
    thedata()  %>% 
      datatable(extensions = 'Buttons',
                options = list(
                  #Each letter is a dif element of a datatable view, this makes buttons the last thing that's shown.
                  
                  
                  buttons = c("copy", "csv", "pdf")),
                filter = list(
                  position = 'top'),
                rownames = FALSE)
  })
  
  
  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("type_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(thedata(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

could someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: You first have to upload or read the file which you select via `fileInput`. See e.g. the example in the docs on how to do that: `?fileInput` or https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/fileInput.html

Comment: @stefan, I edited my code above, but it gives me an error `invalid argument type`

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the PDF output but to get you started: You have to do some adjustments of the code in the examples from `?fileInput`.

Instead of `renderTable` use `reactive`. Also do not assign to an `output`. Instead of `dataTableOutput("csv_dto")` use `dataTableOutput("type_dto")` in the UI.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # setBackgroundColor(color = c("#66e0ff", "#00a3cc", "#003d4d")),
  h1("Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", label = "Choose species"),
      downloadButton("download1", "Download entire Table  as csv")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4("Table 1: Iris"),
      dataTableOutput("type_dto")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  csv_dto <- reactive({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)

    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))

    read.csv(file$datapath)
  })

  thedata <- reactive({
    csv_dto() %>% 
      filter(Type == input$Type)
  })

  output$type_dto <- renderDataTable({
    thedata() %>%
      datatable(
        extensions = "Buttons",
        options = list(
          # Each letter is a dif element of a datatable view, this makes buttons the last thing that's shown.
          buttons = c("copy", "csv", "pdf")
        ),
        filter = list(
          position = "top"
        ),
        rownames = FALSE
      )
  })

  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("type_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(thedata(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I am getting this error  `Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.`
`[31mx[39m Input `..1` must be of size 3 or 1, not size 0.`
`[34mi[39m Input `..1` is `Type == input$Type`